Suspension of users advertising with spams
Reviewing low-quality posts, I see some annoying users posting their ads as a form of answer or question. However, I haven’t seen some cases where the user was suspended.
Right now, seeing my review histories, I have voted to close a lot of casino or other ads, but the posts were simply removed or closed, without any suspensions.
For me, it seems if there’s no suspension for these users, it’s like neglecting illegal scenes, and I think that - only bringing up some additional policies of suspensions for them can prevent more abuses.
P.S. If there are current policies to solve this issue, please leave a comment to let me know and delete this post or something else.
Edit) What I’m talking about is the suspension of the users who posted the ads that are now deleted or closed. Edited just to be clear with the request.

If you see a spam post, the right thing to do is to flag it is as spam - which will both removed the post and hide the content. Som FAQ posts about spam can be found in the tag-info here on meta - if you read through FAQ you can also find what are the consequences for the users posting spam.

Somewhat related: What might a moderator do to a trolling/spamming account and Do spam-only posting users get deleted?

Yep, so there are some systems to suspend them, but… why can’t I see the suspended users by spam? Is it because we didn’t voted him or her as a spam?

This post on [meta.se] seems related to your question: Can an account used to create a post marked as spam from 6 users still be used to create new posts?
BTW I left a few comments in Math Meta Chat.

Do we sometimes have this situation ... an existing user's account is hijacked by a spam bot ?  If so, should that be treated differently than other spam?

@GEdgar Related: What actually happens to someone whose account is hacked by a spammer or hostile? In the accepted answer, Monica Cellio writes that it is very rare (without giving some more detailed stats).

Moderators aren't notified about spam-deleted posts. Moderators can't specifically search for them. Moderators can search for deleted and locked posts, which shows posts deleted as spam and rude/abusive along with other posts. If you feel that more should be done on a specific user/post, then you should raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag and explain the situation. There are user-generated systems which can help bring such deleted posts and users to moderator attention, such as the Charcoal project (I'm an admin), but there's no automatic on-SE notification.
